# name terminal/tabs

Tags: macos, mac, terminal.app

Is there a way to name a terminal window or even better give each tab a name. 
at the moment they just get the underlying process name :  for example a tab running elasticsearch gets the name java

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/343747/504387

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use @bubu 's solution, or you can right click on the tab, select "Inspect Tab", and set the title from there.

Comment: Or press `Cmd-I` to get the inspector.

Comment: Shift-Command-I (Shell > Edit Title) also shows the Inspector and will ensure it selects the Info pane.

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal's Inspector also supports setting the tab title separately from the window title.

Comment: I came across this post in 2021, I'm on macOS Catalina - @DanielBeck solution is what was most helpful for me.  When you do `Cmd-I` you get the inspector window, and in there is a field called "Tab Title."

Answer (score 16):

Well.

```
echo -n -e "\033]0;In soviet russia, the title bar sets you\007"
```

will set your title to "In soviet russia, the title bar sets you"

Comment: Or, even shorter, you can use `echo -ne` instead of `echo -n -e`.

Comment: Seems to me that the soviet russia jokes are not well received here...

Comment: Note that "0" sets both the window and the tab title. As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, you can set them independently, using "1" (tab title) and "2" (window title).

Comment: I recommend using printf instead of echo, because it's simpler and more portable (the "-n" option is not defined in POSIX): `printf '\e]0;...\a'`

Comment: If you're interested in how this works, it uses an [XTerm escape sequence](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-3.html) (also known as a control sequence). A full list of sequences is available [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11apps/X11apps-30.1/xterm/xterm-251/ctlseqs.txt).

Answer (score 4):

If you do this frequently, you can make @bubu's answer a function in your `bash_profile`, like so:

```
tab() {
    echo -ne "\033]0;$*\007"   
}
```

And then just call it followed by the tab name, e.g. `tab Tab Title with Spaces!`