# Name a tab in iterm2, even with pane splits

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, iterm2

I see there are [solutions to name tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/419775/with-bash-iterm2-how-to-name-tabs) in iterm2 when there is a single pane, but it doesn't work well with multiple panes/splits. So if I have two terminals open in a split under a tab, I would need to give each of them the same name to keep the tab name unchanged when I switch between them. And each time I create a new split, I have to rename that one as well.

Is there a way to set a tab name, independent of the panes inside that tab?