# With PowerShell set iTerm2 tab title

Tags: macos, powershell, iterm2

I'm using PowerShell as my shell with iTerm2 on macOS.

I know it's possible on [bash](https://superuser.com/questions/419775/with-bash-iterm2-how-to-name-tabs) and [zsh](https://superuser.com/questions/292652/change-iterm2-window-and-tab-titles-in-zsh) but running the recommended solution doesn't work in powershell, because the ANSI escape doesn't work:

```
PS ~> echo -ne "\033]1;Title\007"
-ne
\033]1;Title\007
PS ~>
```

It should be possible to shell out to i.e. `zsh` from powershell to use these ANSI escapes, but I'd like a PowerShell-native solution.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell [special characters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters) for `\033` ESC is `` "`e" ``, and for `\007` BEL is `` "`a" ``. Using these values:

```
PS ~>"`e]1;Title`a"
```

to change your tab title to "Title". (`echo` is redundant to output values.)

You can instead change the iTerm window title with 2 instead of 1: `` "`e]2;WindowTitle`a" ``. There are several more [iTerm2 escape codes](https://iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html#documentation-escape-codes.html) you can use.